# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, libraries

Ok, first of all this is like the first library I ever load, so remember I can have failed in something incredibly basic and if you can help me in a very **for dummies** language I would appreciate it.

I work with eclipse for windows, and tried to load NeticaJ library.

What I did?

1. Right click on project > Build path > Configure build path > Libraries > Add External JARs > the jar I needed to load.

It had a problem finding the .dll i think:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no NeticaJ in java.library.path

2. A friend of mine told me to modify the "Native library location" on the same Libraries tab, and tell it where to find the .dll's (the folder that comes with the .jar). So I did it, and it changed the problem:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: (PATH_TO_FOLDER)\NeticaJ.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Looking for this error I found some stuff about modifying the .classpath, but it seems *ok* to me, but I don't really know about this, so this is it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="(PATH)/NeticaJ.jar" sourcepath="(PATH)/src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="(PATH)"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

PS: I removed the paths because I don't find them important, they are checked, no fail in there.

Could anyone please help? I have literally no idea about how to solve it and need this to some homework. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I think your problem is not directly related to java or your setup, it is just that the NeticaJ.dll has some other requirements on third party dlls (like the VC++ redistributable for instance, but it's just a wild guess)  installed in the operative system.

Comment: But it did work to my friend with this (or very similar) config. He was working on ubuntu, tho...

Comment: have you tried the steps in the [https://www.norsys.com/netica-j/docs/NeticaJ_Man.pdf](https://www.norsys.com/netica-j/docs/NeticaJ_Man.pdf)? especially, the part 1.5

Comment: Oh god, it was pretty simply explained, thanks @kucing_terbang